# How to modify the Firefox profile used by Watir-Webdriver

Tags: ruby, firefox, selenium, automation, watir-webdriver

I'm working on web-application automation using Ruby 1.9.3p484 and Watir-webdriver (0.8.0) with Firefox 41.0 for Ubuntu.

I want the browser to not load any images. To do that, I try to change the 'permissions.default.image' firefox parameter to 2.

I have tried the following code:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.new
profile['permissions.default.image'] = 2
browser = Watir::Browser.new(:firefox, :profile => profile)
browser.goto url
```

But, the browser keep loading the images. In the about:config page, the 'permissions.default.image' is still set to 1.

Any ideas on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why, but if I use `from_name` method in Selenium class init, then you code is working perfectly:

```
profile = Selenium::WebDriver::Firefox::Profile.from_name "default"
```

Comment: This doesn't work in the newest version of Watir. Getting unknown option error.